# jsf search and result pages

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have two pages - search and result and one bean. If I use ViewScoped, my results do not show. If I use RequestScoped, my page links do not work. How can I fix it? If I place the submit into init with Viewscoped, everything is working fine, but if I do that, how should I get the variables from the form?

My bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Result implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private DAOFactory javabase = DAOFactory.getInstance("javabase.jdbc");
private RecipeDAO recipeDAO = javabase.getRecipeDAO();
private ResourceBundle messages;
@Inject
LocaleBean locale;
private List<Recipe> recipes;
private List<Recipe> recipesView;
private String language;
private List<Page> pagesArray;
private Integer currentPage;

public void init() {
    System.out.println("Language is: " + language);
    String language1 = "en";
    recipes = new ArrayList<>();
    recipes = recipeDAO.searchRecipe(language1);
    int showValue = 5; //split value
    int pages = recipes.size() / showValue;  //pages value
    if (recipes.size() % showValue != 0) {
        pages = pages + 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < recipes.size(); i++) {
        int a = i + 1;
        //System.out.println("i is: " + i + " recipe number is: " + a);
    }
    //System.out.println("pages is: " + pages + " size is: " + recipes.size());
    pagesArray = new ArrayList<>();
    Page page;
    for (int i = 0; i < recipes.size(); i = i + showValue) {
        page = new Page();
        page.setPageDisabled(false);
        page.setFirstItem(i);
        page.setLastItem(i + showValue - 1);
        pagesArray.add(page);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pagesArray.size(); i++) {
        pagesArray.get(i).setPageNumber(i + 1);
    }
    pagesArray.get(pagesArray.size() - 1).setLastItem(recipes.size() - 1);
    /* for (int i = 0; i < pagesArray.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(pagesArray.get(i).getPageNumber() + " " + pagesArray.get(i).getFirstItem() + " " + pagesArray.get(i).getLastItem() + " " + pagesArray.get(i).isPageDisabled());
     }*/
    recipesView = new ArrayList<>();
    Recipe recipe;
    for (int i = pagesArray.get(0).getFirstItem(); i <= pagesArray.get(0).getLastItem(); i++) {
        recipe = new Recipe();
        recipe.setAuthor(recipes.get(i).getAuthor());
        recipe.setId(recipes.get(i).getId());
        recipe.setCreateDate(recipes.get(i).getCreateDate());
        recipe.setTitle(recipes.get(i).getTitle());
        recipesView.add(recipe);
    }
    pagesArray.get(0).setPageDisabled(true);
}

public void doPages() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    this.currentPage = Integer.parseInt(getCountryParam(fc));
    System.out.println(currentPage);
    recipesView = new ArrayList<>();
    Recipe recipe;
    for (int i = pagesArray.get(currentPage - 1).getFirstItem(); i <= pagesArray.get(currentPage - 1).getLastItem(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        recipe = new Recipe();
        recipe.setAuthor(recipes.get(i).getAuthor());
        recipe.setId(recipes.get(i).getId());
        recipe.setCreateDate(recipes.get(i).getCreateDate());
        recipe.setTitle(recipes.get(i).getTitle());
        recipesView.add(recipe);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pagesArray.size(); i++) {
        pagesArray.get(i).setPageDisabled(false);
    }
    pagesArray.get(currentPage - 1).setPageDisabled(true);
}

public String getCountryParam(FacesContext fc) {
    Map<String, String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    return params.get("currentPage");
}


//setters&getters

}
```

My search view:

```
<h:form>
         <h:selectOneMenu value="#{search.language}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="English" itemValue="en"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bulgarian" itemValue="bg"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" type="submit" action="#{search.submit()}">
            <f:param name="lang" value ="#{search.language}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

My result view:

```
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="lang" value="#{result.language}" />
        <f:viewAction action="#{result.init()}" />
    </f:metadata>

<h:form>
            <ui:repeat value="#{result.recipesView}" var="rec">
                <h:link value="#{rec.title}" outcome="recipeshow">
                    <f:param name="id" value="#{rec.id}" />
                </h:link>
                <br/>
                <h:outputText value="#{rec.id}"/><br/>
                <h:outputText value="#{rec.author}"/><br/>
                <h:outputText value="#{rec.createDate}"/><br/>
                <br/>
            </ui:repeat>
            <br/>
            <ui:repeat value="#{result.pagesArray}" var="page">
                <h:commandLink value="#{page.pageNumber}" disabled="#{page.pageDisabled}">
                    <f:ajax listener="#{result.doPages()}" render="@form"/>
                    <f:param name="currentPage" value="#{page.pageNumber}"/>
                </h:commandLink>                  &nbsp;
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:form>
```

My page.java

```
public class Page {

private int pageNumber;
private boolean pageDisabled;
private int firstItem;
private int lastItem;

public int getPageNumber() {
    return pageNumber;
}

public void setPageNumber(int pageNumber) {
    this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
}

public boolean isPageDisabled() {
    return pageDisabled;
}

public void setPageDisabled(boolean pageDisabled) {
    this.pageDisabled = pageDisabled;
}

public int getFirstItem() {
    return firstItem;
}

public void setFirstItem(int firstItem) {
    this.firstItem = firstItem;
}

public int getLastItem() {
    return lastItem;
}

public void setLastItem(int lastItem) {
    this.lastItem = lastItem;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You returned a navigation case outcome from an action method, so your view scoped bean will be recreated, that's why you don't see your results. On the other hand, as you seem to be doing a pagination basing on the information held in the view scope, thus your request scoped beans do not allow for proper pagination.

As to the solution, you should either be doing a postback from your action method, thus returning `null` or `void`, or pass the necessary information to the result view using get parameters.

It is also worth noting that you're preloading too much information in `recipes = recipeDAO.searchRecipe(language);`: you should be loading as much information as is shown in your view, like in: `recipes = recipeDAO.searchRecipe(language, min, max);`.

Comment: I updated the post. I tried  `code`<f:param name="lang" value ="#{search.language}"/>`code`, but it does not work. Thanks for the sql tip.